# php greater than or equal too AND of same type

Tags: php

From the [PHP Manual](http://il.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

```
$a === $b   Identical   TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.

$a <= $b    Less than or equal to   TRUE if $a is less than or equal to $b.
$a >= $b    Greater than or equal to    TRUE if $a is greater than or equal to $b.
```

I want to check first if the $vars are of the same type, then compare them against each other (unless there is an easier 'all in one' method).

I have checked that page and done a number of google searches, but cannot find an 'of same type' operand or func apart from '===', which would only be good if the $vars also matched?

Comment: `if(gettype($a) == gettype($b))`

Comment: it doesn't seem like a healthy coding pattern

Comment: Do you compare integers or doubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with gettype() php function.

```
if( gettype($var1) == gettype($var2) && $var2 < $var1 )
```

Good luck

Comment: Almost (`<=`).. You might as well also use `===` as there's no reason to do lose type checking when you know the type.

Comment: The manual suggests to use `is_*` functions instead: "*For type checking, use is_* functions.*".