# Comparison operators - are there no greater/less and also same data type operator?

Tags: php

Probably answered 1000 times, but it was very hard to search for. This is a general question, I don't have a specific problem that needs solving. E.g I know there's workarounds I can use.

```
$a = "true";
if($a > 0) echo "the number is greater than 0";
```

This evaluates to true, probably because true = 1, and 1 is bigger than 0.

But I don't want the above to evaluate to true, because true is a boolean/string, not a number.

If I was comparing if it was equal to, I could just use === to make sure it was the same data type also, but there doesn't seem to be a similar way to compare using the greater than/less than operators? (e.g >> ?)

Comment: You can use `gettype($var)` to get the type of the variable. Use it in an `if()` statement.

Comment: It seems there aren't which is a pity as leads to messier code. see e.g. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23758178/php-greater-than-or-equal-too-and-of-same-type which suggests using is_a

Comment: ...also >> and << are bitwise shift operators.

Comment: Don't compare apples with oranges to begin with. A good habit would be to ensure that you have the correct data-types before you try to do anything with your variables. You can force this e.g. by having [type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) in your function/method signatures with `strict_types=1`, and when you get the inevitable errors, then you fix your types at the source, before calling functions. Leads to cleaner and saner code. Ie. above, *how would you manage a situation where types differ and can't be compared?*

Answer (score 0):

You probably have noticed that you must write $a = TRUE and not $a ="true" because this whould be a string.

you can check $a with **is_integer** function

```php
$a = TRUE;

if($a > 0 && is_integer($a) ) {
  echo "the number is greater than 0";
}
```